# Suggestions on how to improve the accuracy

Tags: python, machine-learning, classification, tensorflow-estimator

I am new dealing with the tf.estimators api. I have a Dnn classifier that is giving me an accuracy of 60% on the JM1 Software defect prediction dataset from PROMISE repository. I want to imporve the performance of the model in terms of accuracy,precision and recall. I have divided the data into train evaluation and the test data and resampled them to remove the imbalance.I have also tried with different optimizers, activation functions,etc. Here is the code that i have tried.

```
CSV_COLUMNS=['loc','vg','evg','ivg','n','v','l','d','i','e','b','t','lOCode','lOComment','lOBlank','locCodeAndComment','uniq_Op','uniq_Opnd','total_Op','total_Opnd','branchCount','defects']


FEATURES = CSV_COLUMNS[0:len(CSV_COLUMNS) - 1]


LABEL = CSV_COLUMNS[len(CSV_COLUMNS) - 1]


dataset = dataset.astype(int)
X=dataset.iloc[:,:-1].values
y=dataset.iloc[:,-1].values

from imblearn.over_sampling import RandomOverSampler
ros = RandomOverSampler(random_state=120)
X_res, y_res = ros.fit_resample(X, y)

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split 
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X_res, y_res, test_size = 0.3, random_state = 1139)

df_train = np.hstack((X_train, np.atleast_2d(y_train).T))

X_new = X_test
y_new = y_test

X_train_new, X_test_new, y_train_new, y_test_new = train_test_split(X_new, y_new, test_size = 0.3, random_state = 12)

df_eval = np.hstack((X_train_new, np.atleast_2d(y_train_new).T))
df_test = X_test_new

def make_feature_cols():
    input_columns = [tf.feature_column.numeric_column(k) for k in FEATURES]
    return input_columns


df_train = pd.DataFrame(df_train)
df_train=df_train.rename(columns={0: 'loc',1:'vg',2:'evg',3: 'ivg',4:'n',5:'v',6: 'l',7:'d',8:'i',9: 'e',10:'b',11:'t',12: 'lOCode',13:'lOComment',14:'lOBlank',15:'locCodeAndComment',16:'uniq_Op',17:'uniq_Opnd',18:'total_Op',19:'total_Opnd',20:'branchCount',21:'defects'})


df_eval = pd.DataFrame(df_eval)
df_eval=df_eval.rename(columns={0: 'loc',1:'vg',2:'evg',3: 'ivg',4:'n',5:'v',6: 'l',7:'d',8:'i',9: 'e',10:'b',11:'t',12: 'lOCode',13:'lOComment',14:'lOBlank',15:'locCodeAndComment',16:'uniq_Op',17:'uniq_Opnd',18:'total_Op',19:'total_Opnd',20:'branchCount',21:'defects'})


df_test = pd.DataFrame(df_test)
df_test=df_test.rename(columns={0: 'loc',1:'vg',2:'evg',3: 'ivg',4:'n',5:'v',6: 'l',7:'d',8:'i',9: 'e',10:'b',11:'t',12: 'lOCode',13:'lOComment',14:'lOBlank',15:'locCodeAndComment',16:'uniq_Op',17:'uniq_Opnd',18:'total_Op',19:'total_Opnd',20:'branchCount'})



# information display while executing
tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.INFO)

# Creating the directory
OUTDIR = r'C:\Users\dell\Downloads\jm_serial2'
shutil.rmtree(OUTDIR, ignore_errors = True) 
# Start fresh each time


myopt = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.001)


model = tf.estimator.DNNClassifier(feature_columns = make_feature_cols(), 
                               model_dir = OUTDIR, hidden_units=[20, 20], 
                               n_classes=2, optimizer = myopt, dropout=0.2,
                               activation_fn = tf.math.sigmoid)


def make_input_fn(df, num_epochs):
     return tf.estimator.inputs.pandas_input_fn(x = df, y = df[LABEL], shuffle = False, num_epochs = num_epochs)


model.train(input_fn = make_input_fn(df_train, num_epochs = 100))

ev = model.evaluate(input_fn = make_input_fn(df_eval, num_epochs = 1))
print(ev)
```

Edit:
These are the result values that i have got.

```
accuracy = 0.60916734,
accuracy_baseline = 0.5104421, 
auc = 0.6360657, 
auc_precision_recall = 0.6398728, 
average_loss = 0.66607034, 
global_step = 1921, 
label/mean = 0.5104421, 
loss = 84.6828, 
precision = 0.669746, 
prediction/mean = 0.487086, 
recall = 0.46227416
```

Can anyone suggest on what to do to improve the model performance?

Comment: Including all these `print` statements for the very metrics you want improved without their actual outputs in a non-reproducible code is hardly helpful. Plus, RMSE is meaningless in classification problems (you probably mean cross entropy loss).

Comment: For any machine learning model, if we want to improve the accuracy we can definitely do Hyperparameter tuning. It will add a bit to your accuracy.

Comment: @Darshan Jain , i am new to machine learning and could you please tell me how to apply hyperparameter tuning and where exactly can i do it.

Comment: @desertnaut, i am unable to edit the question and so i am sharing the results here...accuracy = 0.60916734, accuracy_baseline = 0.5104421, auc = 0.6360657, auc_precision_recall = 0.6398728, average_loss = 0.66607034, global_step = 1921, label/mean = 0.5104421, loss = 84.6828, precision = 0.669746, prediction/mean = 0.487086, recall = 0.46227416. can you please suggest and ways to improve them?

Comment: You should not share the results in the comments, and you are always able to edit your own question

Comment: Try editing again (there was an edit by another user waiting for approval).

Comment: @desertnaut , i have edited the question

Comment: @SAIPRATYUSHA yes sure. 2 things are required for it. 
1. Try to use RandomizedSearchCV or GridSearchCV. Look for the documentation page. 
2. Select the parameters and their range as per your dataset and then get the best estimators.